# How to assign value of a string variable to a string variable of a structure in c++?

Tags: c++, string, struct

I am trying to assign the value of a string variable to another string variable of a structure. But gdb gives an runtime error. The error is as follows:
    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    0xb7f7c8f8 in std::string::assign(std::string const&) ()
       from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6

My C++ program is:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string>
typedef long unsigned int LUI;
using namespace std;
struct graph {
    string string_node;
    LUI node;
    struct graph *link;
};
struct graph *abc[30];
struct graph *t;
string x;
int main() {
    t = (struct graph *) malloc(sizeof(struct graph *));
    x = "abc";
    t->string_node = x;
    t->link = NULL;
    abc[0] = t;
    cout << "Value is " << abc[0]->string_node << endl;
    cout << "end";

    return 0;
}
```

Please help me to store the value of x into t->string_node. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you read a lesson of cpp before try ? you really should. http://www.learncpp.com/

Comment: Use `new` to allocate memory properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t = (struct graph *) malloc(sizeof(struct graph *));
```

`graph` is a class. It contains C++ classes, specifically it contains a `std::string`.

All C++ classes must be constructed in dynamic scope using the `new` operator. They cannot be constructed with the C library function `malloc()`, which knows absolutely nothing, whatsoever, about C++ classes. Doing so results in undefined behavior (not to mention that your malloc-ed size is wrong, anyway).

Now that you're writing C++ code, you need to completely forget that `malloc()`, `realloc()`, and `free()` ever existed, and always use `new` and `delete`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're allocating a `struct` with `malloc`, but that `struct` does not have only POD (plain old data) members: it has a `std::string` member, and `std::string` objects expect to be *constructed*.  Simply allocating memory for it with `malloc` will not invoke the `std::string` constructor, and consequently attempting to interact with that `std::string` later will result in undefined behavior since that object is in a bad state.

You instead should use `new` to allocate your `struct`, and that will properly allocate memory *and* invoke the default constructor for each member. (Conversely, you should release that memory with `delete` instead of `free` to properly invoke the *destructor* of each member.)

Alternatively, it is possible to use ["placement `new`"](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new) to construct an object in memory you've already allocated, but this is not something that you should normally need to do.